# Worklight form-based authentication, access denied error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to run the sample code from the tutorial of IBM,
[Form_based_authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGTxf.png), but it doesn't work correctly.

It doesn't show the login form, and when I click on the "Call protected adapter proc" button, it shows an access denied error like this one:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your scenario.

- Open the Chrome DevTools and inspect the console view when you click on the button. What errors do you see?
- Did you add any environment or are you simply previewing the common web resources?
- Anything else about your environment that you did not mention?

  1. [Imported the Form-based authentication sample](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/FormBasedAuthenticationProject.zip) (.zip file) for Worklight 6.0
  2. Started the server, deployed the adapter and application
  3. Opened Worklight Console
  4. Previewed the common web resources
  5. Clicked on "Call protected adapter proc"
  6. Entered random values for username/password (since a non-validating authenticator is being used in this sample
  7. Clicked on "Call protected adapter proc" again

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clear the data of the app from the setting than it will work. Form based authentication work for same day or same session after that it will throw error in console

"[ERROR   ] FWLSE0335E: Authorization failed: ClientId 8a822ed6a93bec9c9f810e128cdb5dba4bb8f762 was not found on the server. [project xyz]
"